# How do I find if anything in a list is in a string and determine what that "anything" is?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, user-input, string-parsing

I have a need to read from a user input and parse it into 3 parts, the first piece is the row value, the second is the condition (==, !=, > etc.) and the third is the compare-value.
User input: 0=="6/1/2014 0:00:00" --> Therefore, row would be 0, condition would be "==" and compare-value would be "6/1/2014 0:00:00"

Here is what I have:

```
    promptList = ["0 == 6/12/16 00:00:00", "1 > 47.20"]
    for prompt in promptList:
    if any(comparator in prompt for comparator in comparatorsList):
        prompt = prompt.split(comparator)
        row = prompt[0].strip()
        condition = prompt[1].strip()
        comparator = str(comparator).strip()
        print(row, comparator, condition) #test to see print statement, not needed
```

However, it says that I do not have comparator defined. I need comparator to know what to split the string by because you never know where the comparator would show up (i.e: 0 == 0  **VS.** 20124 > 6/2/12 00:32:10)

How do I set my 3 variables!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `comparator` is scoped within your generator comprehension and won't exist outside of it.  Instead of using the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) construct, which is throwing away valuable information here, namely which comparator actually is contained, you could just expand it out into a for loop instead:

```
comparatorsList = set(["==", "!=", ">", ">=", "<=", "<"])
promptList = ["0 == 6/12/16 00:00:00", "1 > 47.20"]

for prompt in promptList:
    for comparator in comparatorsList:
        if comparator in prompt:
            prompt = prompt.split(comparator)
            row = prompt[0].strip()
            condition = prompt[1].strip()
            comparator = str(comparator).strip()
            print(row, comparator, condition) 
            break
```

Prints:

```
('0', '==', '6/12/16 00:00:00')
('1', '>', '47.20')
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined `comparator` variable inside comprehension used in any, so its scope is limited to scope of this comprehension.

You can replace

```
if any(comparator in prompt for comparator in comparatorsList):
```

with something like

```
comparator = next((x for x in comparatorsList if x in prompt), None)
if comparator is not None:
```

Or you can simple use regular expression. You did not specify any constraints on left and right value, so I assume they can be any:

```
import re
rv = re.match("(.*)(==|!=|>)(.*)", "6 == 2")
```

`rv.groups()` will have matched groups, first one with left value, second one with comparasion, and third one with right value. You can fine tune this regex to limit left and right value types.